# Nombre de objeto no valido SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Quiero crear un procedimiento para inicio de sesión pero me arroja un error de nombre de objeto no valido.

Adjunto SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAccesoSistema
(
@prmUser varchar(50),
@prmPassword varchar(50)
)
AS
    Begin
        SELECT E.idEmpleado, E.usuario, E.clave
        FROM Empleado E
        WHERE E.usuario = @prmUser and E.clave = @prmPassword
    END
```

Comment: Podras mostrar el error que te muestra?

Comment: Si ejecutas el comando `EXEC spAccesoSistema '', ''`, te muestra el error? Creao que es un error tonto de sintaxis.